# MySQL syntax error(the query works perfectly fine in mysql but somehow ends up giving error in jsp)

Tags: mysql, jsp, jdbc

I am trying to update database in mysql but when i use the query in mysql it works perfectly fine......but when i update it through jsp it gives me an error as

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1

this is query of JSP: (in content i do not add any closing brackets like ')')

```
insert into location_"+username+" 
  values('"+coordinates+"','"+content+"',"+latitude+","+longitude+");
```

i use stmt.executeUpdate(q1);
the above query is stored in q1..

this is query in mysql:(this works absolutely fine)
 insert into location_user1 values('{lat: 19.2222, lng: 73.9781}','random coordinate from database', 19.2222, 73.9781);

i have found out that this error is somewhat common..yet i could not find out any solution...PLease Help!! Thank You!! This error is so frustrating..

Comment: try add a space between values and  (

Comment: Side-Node: Creating tables per "User" is a bad idea. You should better use a single table with another column "user_id".

Comment: Please post the actual code involved (a [mcve]), and the full exception stacktrace. Also note that as shown, your code is fundamentally unsafe because it is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Answer (score -1):

Try printing q1 and execute the printed output in MySQL.

At jsp end, the query is not getting properly built and this only is leading to the issue.